# Socket connection between Raspberry Pi and Android app can't reconnect

Tags: android, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make an app on Android that talks to a Raspberry Pi through a socket connection. Everything works if I start the two apps from nothing.

I have a loop on each that pings the other and resets the socket if a connection break is detected.

So the connection should be able to handle the Pi or Android going offline then coming back.

But for some reason, after I kill the android app and bring it back - the new socket connection is made but no data is read from the stream (on the android device) even though the Pi is sending it data. The Android device times out when trying to read even though the Pi has sent a ping message.

I don't know if the problem is on the Pi (python) side, or on the Android (java) side.

When a connection is reset on the Pi, the following happens (this also happens on launch to create the original socket, and it works that first time):

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCLET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
self.socket.settimeout(0.001)
self.socket.bind(ip,port)
self.socket.listen(1)
```

Below is performed in a loop, until the connection is accepted:

```
(self.connection,self.addr) = self.socket.accept()
```

Once the socket is accepted, I use `self.connection.send()` to send bytes; and `self.connection.recv(1024)` to receive them.

On the Android side, the following happens when connecting on first launch, or reconnecting after the socket is detected to be gone:

```
s = new Socket();
s.setSoTimeout(200);
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 200);
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
```

1. `writer` is a `BufferedWriter`
2. `br` is a `BufferedReader`. `br.readLine()` to read data,
3. `writer.write(Str)`
4. `writer.flush()` to write data.

Am I omitting something that makes this socket code work after the first attempt?

Comment: `When a connection is reset on the Pi, the following happens ` The pi is the server and it looks if you create a new server socket at connection loss. No not needed. Only a loop to 
(self.connection,self.addr) = self.socket.accept()
 wiill do.

Comment: `self.socket.settimeout(0.001)` How many ms would that be?

Comment: `# Below is performed in a loop, until the connection is accepted:` ? No. .accept() will wait until a client connects.

Comment: Are you calling `accept()` a second time after the first incoming connection? You need to post more code. NB 0.001ms is a throughly ludicrous timeout, and so is 200ms. Use something practical, like tens of seconds.